# Compile single c# file on command line with net6/net7 (Windows)

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

I have a number of tools that are more like scripts that full-fledged programs and in the olden days I would simply call the `csc.exe` compiler and throw the `program.cs` in there like this:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
  /out:NasPath.exe
  /target:exe
  /optimize+
  /debug-
  /platform:x64
  NasPath.cs
```

I'm pretty certain that .net 4.8.1 will be around on Windows for quite some time but for my learning journey I was curious if there's a simple way to compile such a C# file in `net7.0` or if I always need at least a `.csproj` file for that.

Comment: Not quite an answer, but you may be interested to look at LINQPad, which makes it very easy to write a simple expression, a few statements, or an entire program, run them as scripts, and visualize their results. It includes a command-line tool for executing the files as scripts from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking whether the `dotnet` tool is capable of compiling single `Program.cs` file into an executable - bypassing the creation of the .csproj file - then the answer is **probably no?** - I haven't found a way to do that.

On the other hand, the .NET 7.0's `.csproj` file size can be very small, and even can be created-and-deleted-afterwards from within your scripts:

```
echo ^<Project Sdk=^"Microsoft.NET.Sdk^"^>^<PropertyGroup^>^<OutputType^>Exe^</OutputType^>^<TargetFramework^>net7.0^</TargetFramework^>^</PropertyGroup^>^</Project^> > MyApp.csproj
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build .
DEL MyApp.csproj
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile a single C# file without creating a dotnet project. You can use the that command

```
dotnet script Example.cs
```

To use this command, you must install the dotnet script with

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-script
```

and make sure that the "your user path/.dotnet/tool" folder is added to the "path" environment variable.

The `csc Example.cs` command is valid for versions before Net 5.0.

But if you want to compile and obtain obj and exe files instead of running a specific file.
First, create a ".csproj" file with the same name in the directory where the cs file is located.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

   <PropertyGroup>
     <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
     <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

You need to enter that codes above and save. And then you need to run that command below :

```
dotnet build yourprojectfolderpath -o outfolderpath
```

Comment: Note that `dotnet script` runs C# Script files (`.csx`), which have a slightly different syntax from actual C#. They add syntax for things like including external libraries.